# Json string partial deserial to Java object with embeded another Json string using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have one java object

```
class packet {
    int id;
    String sender;
    String content;  // this is an embedded json string
}
```

here is my original json string

```
{"id":0,"sender":"jack","content":{"title":"test1","author":"john"}}.
```

I want Jackson only parse outer id, sender, and keep the

```
content = {"title":"test1","author":"john"},
```

how to do it?

I have tried `@JsonUnwrapped` on content variable, but it don't work.

Comment: Parse the JSON into a nest of Maps, then reserialize the "content" Map.

Answer (score 4):

In order to use an "embedded" JSON string you can use the [JsonNode](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) class. If you specify the `Packet` class like this:

```
public class Packet {
    private final int id;
    private final String sender;
    private final JsonNode content;  // this is the embedded content

    @JsonCreator
    public Packet(@JsonProperty("id") final int id,
                  @JsonProperty("sender") final String sender,
                  @JsonProperty("content") final JsonNode content) {

        this.id = id;
        this.sender = sender;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public JsonNode getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getSender() {
        return sender;
    }
}
```

Then, you can do your mapping according to this:

```
final String json = "{\"id\":0,\"sender\":\"jack\",\"content\":{\"title\":\"test1\",\"author\":\"john\"}}";
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

final Packet packet = mapper.readValue(json, Packet.class);

System.out.println(packet.getContent().toString());
```

The output will be:

> {"title":"test1","author":"john"}

Also note that `JsonNode` has methods so that it is still possible to get the inner attributes (methods are called `get()` and `path()`).

**Edit:**
After some input from @HotLicks I have provided a shorter example of the code as well. Please note that this code does not follow best practices for e.g. immutable objects but it is, well, short. However, I would strongly recommend to encapsulate POJOs properly using immutable objects, proper constructors and to avoid field deserialization and instead use a creator-method.

```
public class Packet {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private int id;

    @JsonProperty("sender")
    private String sender;

    @JsonProperty("content")
    private JsonNode content;  // this is the embedded content

    // Other methods...
}
```

Comment: Gad!  That solution is easily 3 times longer than simply parsing, extracting element "content" from the resulting Map, then reserializing.

Comment: @HotLicks, you may be right. But since the OP already had a POJO and wanted to keep one field "raw" it was easily solved with substituting just one member of the class (the content-member). Please observe that it is only the POJO that has changed and I added some "best practices" such as making the object immutable on my own. But, it is sure possible to work with nested Maps. The downside of that approach is obviously that you lose all type safety, you miss out on parsing errors (e.g. if there is an error in the JSON such as the wrong name on a key) etc.

Comment: @HotLicks, I have provided a shorter example using the same code (`JsonNode`). IMO, nicer than dealing with `Map<String, ?>` since `JsonNode` offers a bunch of nice methods for working with the content (e.g. `path()`).